# How to collect data using multiple eager loading in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, orm, eager-loading

I'm just wondering why my code is not working, I mean, after I collect single data using eager loading, after that, if I collect the nested relationship, it returns an error. Please see my code below.

**Error**

> Trying to get property of non-object

**My Code**
*Controller.php*

```
$ex = Exam::with('answers', 'child.answers')->find($id);
$exam = collect($ex->answers);
$exams = $exam->merge(collect($ex->child->answers));

return view('school.exam.view', compact('exams'));
```

*view.blade.php*

```
@foreach($exams as $exam)
  <li>{{ $exam->name }}</li>
@endforeach
```

What should I do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Because this line here

> $exam = collect($exam->answers);

Maybe you wanted this

> $quizzes = collect($exam->answers);

EDIT:

It's because `$exam->child` is a collection. You need to loop through each childs and get the answers. You also should have named the relation into `childs` for clarity.

```
$ex = Exam::with('answers', 'childs.answers')->find($id);
$exam = collect($ex->answers);
foreach(collect($ex->childs) as $child) {
    $exams = $exam->merge(collect($child->answers));
}

return view('school.exam.view', compact('exams'));
```

Comment: I have edited it. Please take a look again. Sorry for the typo

Comment: What is the relationship of Exam and Child? is it 1:M?

Comment: it's belongsToMany